# Multiple comparison after ANOVA - reordering factor levels post hoc test

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 15 factor levels:

```
Value <- runif(225) 
df <- data.frame(Variant=rep(c(1:15), each=15),
      Value=Value)

df$Variant <- factor(df$Variant)
levels(df$Variant)
```

I am using ANOVA and after Duncan test:

```
model <- lm(Value~Variant, data=df)
anova(model)

library(agricolae)
out <- duncan.test(model, "Variant", group=F); out
```

After Duncan test I get the following comparison order of factor levels:

1-10,1-11,1-12,1-13,1-14,1-15,1-2,1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, 1-7, 1-8, 1-9, 10-11, 10-12, 10-13, 10-14, 10-15 etc.

How can I manually change this order like this:

1-2,1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, 1-7, 1-8, 1-9, 1-10, 1-11, 1-12, 1-13, 1-14, 1-15, 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6 etc.

Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```r
ord <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(row.names(out$comparison), " - "), as.numeric))
out$comparison[order(ord[,1], ord[,2]),]
#>           difference pvalue signif.         LCL        UCL
#> 1 - 2    0.038843696 0.7161         -0.16755260 0.24523999
#> 1 - 3   -0.082464843 0.4965         -0.31294877 0.14801909
#> 1 - 4   -0.026633590 0.8112         -0.23991700 0.18664982
#> 1 - 5   -0.008944756 0.9333         -0.21534105 0.19745153
#> 1 - 6   -0.113440226 0.3555         -0.34762702 0.12074656
#> 1 - 7   -0.033132833 0.7772         -0.25544634 0.18918067
#> 1 - 8   -0.006618202 0.9470         -0.20269177 0.18945536
#> 1 - 9    0.046838403 0.6741         -0.16644500 0.26012181
#> 1 - 10  -0.091429309 0.4543         -0.32388649 0.14102787
#> 1 - 11  -0.140899981 0.2522         -0.37661897 0.09481900
#> 1 - 12   0.001178870 0.9906         -0.19489469 0.19725243
#> 1 - 13  -0.047673502 0.6884         -0.27319857 0.17785157
#> 1 - 14  -0.031176107 0.7857         -0.24953106 0.18717885
#> 1 - 15  -0.074161352 0.5370         -0.30236480 0.15404210
#> 2 - 3   -0.121308539 0.3226         -0.35549533 0.11287825
#> 2 - 4   -0.065477286 0.5752         -0.28779079 0.15683622
#> 2 - 5   -0.047788453 0.6766         -0.26614341 0.17056650
#> 2 - 6   -0.152283922 0.2177         -0.38937226 0.08480442
#> 2 - 7   -0.071976529 0.5492         -0.30017998 0.15622692
#> 2 - 8   -0.045461898 0.6831         -0.25874530 0.16782151
#> 2 - 9    0.007994707 0.9360         -0.18807886 0.20406827
#> 3 - 4    0.055831254 0.6330         -0.16648225 0.27814476
#> 3 - 5    0.073520087 0.5354         -0.15200498 0.29904515
#> 3 - 6   -0.030975383 0.7719         -0.23737167 0.17542091
#> 3 - 7    0.049332010 0.6577         -0.16395140 0.26261542
#> 3 - 8    0.075846641 0.5277         -0.15235681 0.30405009
#> 3 - 9    0.129303246 0.2943         -0.10641574 0.36502223
#> 4 - 5    0.017688833 0.8590         -0.17838473 0.21376240
#> 4 - 6   -0.086806636 0.4694         -0.31501009 0.14139682
#> 4 - 7   -0.006499243 0.9515         -0.21289553 0.19989705
#> 4 - 8    0.020015388 0.8514         -0.18638090 0.22641168
#> 4 - 9    0.073471993 0.5357         -0.15205307 0.29899706
#> 5 - 6   -0.104495470 0.3877         -0.33497940 0.12598846
#> 5 - 7   -0.024188077 0.8282         -0.23747148 0.18909533
#> 5 - 8    0.002326554 0.9814         -0.19374701 0.19840012
#> 5 - 9    0.055783160 0.6333         -0.16653035 0.27809667
#> 6 - 7    0.080307393 0.4913         -0.14200611 0.30262090
#> 6 - 8    0.106822024 0.3812         -0.12563515 0.33927920
#> 6 - 9    0.160278629 0.1961         -0.07804271 0.39859996
#> 7 - 8    0.026514631 0.8172         -0.19184032 0.24486959
#> 7 - 9    0.079971236 0.5097         -0.15051269 0.31045517
#> 8 - 9    0.053456605 0.6407         -0.16489835 0.27181156
#> 10 - 2   0.130273005 0.2906         -0.10544598 0.36599199
#> 10 - 3   0.008964466 0.9283         -0.18710910 0.20503803
#> 10 - 4   0.064795720 0.5852         -0.16072935 0.29032079
#> 10 - 5   0.082484553 0.4920         -0.14571890 0.31068801
#> 10 - 6  -0.022010917 0.8251         -0.21808448 0.17406265
#> 10 - 7   0.058296476 0.6107         -0.16005848 0.27665143
#> 10 - 8   0.084811107 0.4842         -0.14567282 0.31529504
#> 10 - 9   0.138267713 0.2641         -0.09882063 0.37535605
#> 10 - 11 -0.049470671 0.6431         -0.25586696 0.15692562
#> 10 - 12  0.092608180 0.4517         -0.14157861 0.32679497
#> 10 - 13  0.043755807 0.6944         -0.16952760 0.25703921
#> 10 - 14  0.060253203 0.6062         -0.16206030 0.28256671
#> 10 - 15  0.017267958 0.8716         -0.18912833 0.22366425
#> 11 - 2   0.179743677 0.1456         -0.05857766 0.41806501
#> 11 - 3   0.058435138 0.5995         -0.15484827 0.27171854
#> 11 - 4   0.114266391 0.3442         -0.11621754 0.34475032
#> 11 - 5   0.131955224 0.2776         -0.10050195 0.36441240
#> 11 - 6   0.027459755 0.7828         -0.16861381 0.22353332
#> 11 - 7   0.107767148 0.3617         -0.11775792 0.33329222
#> 11 - 8   0.134281779 0.2726         -0.09990501 0.36846857
#> 11 - 9   0.187738384 0.1296         -0.05170032 0.42717709
#> 11 - 12  0.142078851 0.2509         -0.09500949 0.37916719
#> 11 - 13  0.093226479 0.4236         -0.12908703 0.31553999
#> 11 - 14  0.109723874 0.3591         -0.11847958 0.33792733
#> 11 - 15  0.066738629 0.5597         -0.15161633 0.28509358
#> 12 - 2   0.037664826 0.7053         -0.15840874 0.23373839
#> 12 - 3  -0.083643714 0.4940         -0.31610089 0.14881346
#> 12 - 4  -0.027812460 0.8084         -0.24616741 0.19054249
#> 12 - 5  -0.010123627 0.9277         -0.22340703 0.20315978
#> 12 - 6  -0.114619097 0.3535         -0.35033808 0.12109989
#> 12 - 7  -0.034311704 0.7730         -0.25983677 0.19121336
#> 12 - 8  -0.007797073 0.9418         -0.21419336 0.19859922
#> 12 - 9   0.045659533 0.6690         -0.16073676 0.25205582
#> 12 - 13 -0.048852373 0.6848         -0.27705583 0.17935108
#> 12 - 14 -0.032354977 0.7823         -0.25466848 0.18995853
#> 12 - 15 -0.075340222 0.5347         -0.30582415 0.15514371
#> 13 - 2   0.086517198 0.4754         -0.14396673 0.31700113
#> 13 - 3  -0.034791341 0.7447         -0.24118763 0.17160495
#> 13 - 4   0.021039912 0.8503         -0.19224349 0.23432332
#> 13 - 5   0.038728746 0.7355         -0.17962621 0.25708370
#> 13 - 6  -0.065766724 0.5655         -0.28412168 0.15258823
#> 13 - 7   0.014540669 0.8839         -0.18153289 0.21061423
#> 13 - 8   0.041055300 0.7258         -0.18125821 0.26336881
#> 13 - 9   0.094511905 0.4391         -0.13794527 0.32696908
#> 13 - 14  0.016497396 0.8773         -0.18989890 0.22289369
#> 13 - 15 -0.026487850 0.7903         -0.22256141 0.16958571
#> 14 - 2   0.070019803 0.5552         -0.15550526 0.29554487
#> 14 - 3  -0.051288737 0.6544         -0.26964369 0.16706622
#> 14 - 4   0.004542517 0.9636         -0.19153105 0.20061608
#> 14 - 5   0.022231350 0.8352         -0.18416494 0.22862764
#> 14 - 6  -0.082264120 0.4877         -0.30778919 0.14326095
#> 14 - 7  -0.001956726 0.9843         -0.19803029 0.19411684
#> 14 - 8   0.024557904 0.8256         -0.18872550 0.23784131
#> 14 - 9   0.078014510 0.5159         -0.15018894 0.30621796
#> 14 - 15 -0.042985245 0.6996         -0.25626865 0.17029816
#> 15 - 2   0.113005048 0.3539         -0.11945213 0.34546222
#> 15 - 3  -0.008303492 0.9335         -0.20437706 0.18777007
#> 15 - 4   0.047527762 0.6783         -0.17082719 0.26588272
#> 15 - 5   0.065216595 0.5768         -0.15709691 0.28753010
#> 15 - 6  -0.039278874 0.7244         -0.25256228 0.17400453
#> 15 - 7   0.041028519 0.7009         -0.16536777 0.24742481
#> 15 - 8   0.067543150 0.5693         -0.15798192 0.29306822
#> 15 - 9   0.120999755 0.3239         -0.11318703 0.35518654
```

EDIT

---

The OP has asked how this might be achieved with Roman numerals. In that case, you would need to do:

```
install.packages("gtools")
ord <- do.call(rbind, 
               lapply(strsplit(row.names(out$comparison), "\\W"), 
                      function(x) gtools::roman2int(x[x != ""])))
out$comparison[order(ord[,1], ord[,2]),]
```

Comment: And how can I use this code if I have letters instead of numbers? e.g. "I.", "II.", "III.", "IV.", "V.", "VI.", "VII.", "VIII.", "IX.", "X.", "XI.", "XII.", "XIII.", "XIV.", "XV." Thank You

Comment: Can I use this code if I have letters instead of numbers? e.g. "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" and control, I want to compare the following order: control-A, control-B, control-C,control-D, control-E, control-F. Thank you very much.

Comment: @BaltazárTivadar yes, these should sort in order. To get the letters from the row names do `gsub("control-", "", row.names(out))`